# Change the setTimeout() function from JSDOM to the node.js default?

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron, jsdom

Im using node.js with the ytdl-core and electron package an getting an error when using the ytdl.getInfo() function. The error only occurs when calling the .getInfo() function in a renderer file of electron, in the main file it`s working fine, so im sure it has to do with the html file the script is linked to.

The Error message is this and occurs more than once:

```
Uncaught TypeError: setTimeout(...).unref is not a function
    at Map.set (C:\Users\Anton\Desktop\nodetestenv\node_modules\ytdl-core\lib\cache.js:12)
    at Map.getOrSet (C:\Users\Anton\Desktop\nodetestenv\node_modules\ytdl-core\lib\cache.js:28)
    at Function.exports.<computed> [as getInfo] (C:\Users\Anton\Desktop\nodetestenv\node_modules\ytdl-core\lib\info.js:461)
    at down.js:3
C:\Users\Anton\Desktop\nodetestenv\node_modules\ytdl-core\lib\cache.js:12 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: setTimeout(...).unref is not a function
    at Map.set (C:\Users\Anton\Desktop\nodetestenv\node_modules\ytdl-core\lib\cache.js:12)
    at Map.getOrSet (C:\Users\Anton\Desktop\nodetestenv\node_modules\ytdl-core\lib\cache.js:28)
    at Object.exports.<computed> [as getBasicInfo] (C:\Users\Anton\Desktop\nodetestenv\node_modules\ytdl-core\lib\info.js:461)
    at exports.getInfo (C:\Users\Anton\Desktop\nodetestenv\node_modules\ytdl-core\lib\info.js:352)
    at C:\Users\Anton\Desktop\nodetestenv\node_modules\ytdl-core\lib\info.js:461
    at Map.getOrSet (C:\Users\Anton\Desktop\nodetestenv\node_modules\ytdl-core\lib\cache.js:27)
    at Function.exports.<computed> [as getInfo] (C:\Users\Anton\Desktop\nodetestenv\node_modules\ytdl-core\lib\info.js:461)
    at down.js:3
C:\Users\Anton\Desktop\nodetestenv\node_modules\ytdl-core\lib\cache.js:12 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: setTimeout(...).unref is not a function
    at Map.set (C:\Users\Anton\Desktop\nodetestenv\node_modules\ytdl-core\lib\cache.js:12)
    at Map.getOrSet (C:\Users\Anton\Desktop\nodetestenv\node_modules\ytdl-core\lib\cache.js:28)
    at getHTMLWatchPageBody (C:\Users\Anton\Desktop\nodetestenv\node_modules\ytdl-core\lib\info.js:113)
    at C:\Users\Anton\Desktop\nodetestenv\node_modules\ytdl-core\lib\info.js:127
    at Map.getOrSet (C:\Users\Anton\Desktop\nodetestenv\node_modules\ytdl-core\lib\cache.js:27)
    at getIdentityToken (C:\Users\Anton\Desktop\nodetestenv\node_modules\ytdl-core\lib\info.js:126)
    at setIdentityToken (C:\Users\Anton\Desktop\nodetestenv\node_modules\ytdl-core\lib\info.js:266)
    at getWatchJSONPage (C:\Users\Anton\Desktop\nodetestenv\node_modules\ytdl-core\lib\info.js:277)
    at async retryFunc (C:\Users\Anton\Desktop\nodetestenv\node_modules\ytdl-core\lib\info.js:207)
    at async pipeline (C:\Users\Anton\Desktop\nodetestenv\node_modules\ytdl-core\lib\info.js:150)
```

I did some research and it seems to has smth. to do with the fact that my program is using the JSDom setTimeout() function and not the node.js version. I did not quite understand the people, which hat a similar issue, arguing on GitHub. So I`m asking how do i make it use the node.js setTimeout() function. I created a 2. node project and reproduced the issue.

Here are some of the GitHub links where i didn`t quite understand what was going on:

https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/21162

https://github.com/sindresorhus/get-port/pull/40

https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/9033

https://github.com/grpc/grpc-node/issues/1077

https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/1909

https://github.com/jsdom/jsdom/blob/a6acac4e9dec4f859fff22676fb4e9eaa9139787/lib/jsdom/browser/Window.js#L176

Here is my code from the 2. project:

main.js, i just copied from the electron side

```
const { app, BrowserWindow } = require('electron');

function createWindow () {
  const win = new BrowserWindow({
    width: 800,
    height: 600,
    webPreferences: {
      nodeIntegration: true
    }
  })

  win.loadFile('index.html')
  win.openDevTools();
}

app.whenReady().then(createWindow)

app.on('window-all-closed', () => {
  if (process.platform !== 'darwin') {
    app.quit()
  }
})

app.on('activate', () => {
  if (BrowserWindow.getAllWindows().length === 0) {
    createWindow()
  }
})
```

my index.html file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Hello World!</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline';" />
</head>
<body style="background: white;">
    <h1>Hello World!</h1>
    <p>
        We are using node <script>document.write(process.versions.node)</script>,
        Chrome <script>document.write(process.versions.chrome)</script>,
        and Electron <script>document.write(process.versions.electron)</script>.
    </p>
    <script src="down.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

my downloader file:

```
const ytdl = require("ytdl-core");

ytdl.getInfo("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZA6LEWQf6us").then(
      (info) => {
          console.log(info);
      }
);
```

my package.json file:

```
{
  "name": "nodetestenv",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "test node things",
  "main": "main.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "electron ."
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "electron": "^11.1.0"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "ytdl-core": "^4.1.5"
  }
}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

i found a helpful source. When starting electron there is a panel Issues, which seems to be new, where i found a link to [this](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/security/csp?utm_source=devtools#eval_too) Website, explaining that my Issue comes from the Content Securitz Policy. After I saw this error, my node.js application also told me, that there is a new update for ytdl-core. This wasn`t there yesterday i think and updating solved the Issue for me.

Here is a photo from my project with the error and the message. It`s my actual project because i found the fix in my test enviroment.
[Picture of Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DArYT.png)